# How's Virtual DOM implementation is different than createDocumentFragment() if no state is observed?

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

Virtual DOM is a light weight copy of DOM, maintained / cached locally before inserting it into actual DOM. We can change it as we want and then save to our real DOM tree. It uses efficient diff algorithms to update changes back and forth and other use cases.

This all is done to avoid direct manipulation with DOM as it's an expensive operation.
 We have **document.createDocumentFragment()** method which can be used in JavaScript, which also creates imaginary tree node objects to insert into DOM.

I would like to know, if I do not have view / component which need to observe on any state or bidirectional binding(e.g. just render template by passed options, and handle events on DOM), does Virtual DOM will really make a difference in such scenarios? 
Or it is as good as createDocumentFragment() if all it has to do is just rendering and no observing on state.

Comment: The answer depends **entirely** on your scenario. I'm not sure that in the scenario you describe that using a doc fragment would be better than just more typical DOM manipulation and modification. You need to test the scenario you have in mind. React is more than just a Virtual DOM implementation and provides component abstractions an more ... those may be of value.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest answer is that NodeJS does(/will) not have `document.createDocumentFragment`, nor `document.createElement` or any such thing.

The point of VirtualDOM is to allow for not only large-scale edits to systems where DOM will later be injected, but also to allow for *any* edits in an environment where the DOM just plain does not exist.

This is the largest difference between practical application of `DocumentFragment`s and VirtualDOM.

Added benefits in terms of specific instances of DOM virtualization would be that certain view libraries (React, say) make dealing with these things quite simple, compared to manual insertion into fragments and their children.

Comment: There is nothing related to NodeJS here. You can use "document.createDocumentFragment" in your javascript to create fragments and then add whole tree to the DOM. Also, I edited question for same.

Comment: Well, in that case it simply comes down to what libraries you are using, and what *they* use. Because if you're doing it all by hand, without so much as helper functions, switching between the two is going to offer you practically no benefit, for extra memory usage... The point of VirtualDOM is to... Vritualize the DOM.  ...not to make it better or faster, or more magical or even easier to work with. Libraries which utilize VirtualDOM (either the technique or the actual virtual-dom library) might do all of those things and more. Don't switch to do it by hand...

Comment: There are also benefits in integration-testing, for simple tests, where you don't want to spend the time building up and tearing down HTML pages, specifically to have DOM access, to check the value of an element/attribute (such as running a CI setup using Mocha). But again, if testing doesn't count as a benefit, either, then it's still down to the Elms and the Reacts and the like.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual DOM is a virtual representation of the UI tree. Its name is misleading as it's not linked to the DOM any more. Nowadays React can be used for web apps with `react-dom` or for mobile apps with `react-native`.

It's true that DocumentFragment and Virtual DOM are similar: tree like structures containing nodes with similar information.
One could indeed use DocumentFragment to track changes and update the DOM when necessary. However it wouldn't be possible to use it on native development. Also the nodes will contain unnecessary properties and methods.