# Rendering part of a React tree in a document fragment to avoid rendering DOM Nodes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

There is some cases where I would like to use React without rendering actual DOM Nodes. For example, when using `<canvas>` it would be nice to be able to add children to the canvas like so:

```
<canvas>
    <Rectangle>
        <Circle />
    </Rectangle>
<canvas>
```

The `<Rectangle />` or `<Circle />` could have access to the canvas element by either passing it as props or with context and they could draw on it using both `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`.

There is libraries that does something similar like [react-pixi](https://github.com/Izzimach/react-pixi) or [react-three](https://github.com/Izzimach/react-three) but they mess a lot with react internal functions.

At first I tough I could have the render function of `<Rectangle />` or `<Circle />` returning either `this.props.children` or `null` but this approach doesn't work if some children are an array. It then needs to be wrapped in an element.

For example, if `<Rectangle />` and `<Circle />` render function look like this:

```
render: function()
{
    return this.props.children || null;
}
```

This won't works

```
<canvas>
    <Rectangle>
        <Circle />
        <Circle />
    </Rectangle>
<canvas>
```

So I've figured out a solution using document fragment.

First there is a top `FragmentTree` component that needs to wrap anything inside `<canvas>`.

Something like this:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var FragmentTree = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function()
    {
        var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        var rootNode = document.createElement('div');
        fragment.appendChild(rootNode);
        return {
            fragment: fragment,
            rootNode: rootNode
        };
    },

    render: function()
    {
        return null;
    },

    componentDidMount: function()
    {
        if (this.props.children) {
            this.renderChildren();
        }
    },

    componentDidUpdate: function(prevProps, prevState)
    {
        var elementChanged = this.state.element !== prevState.element;
        var childrenChanged = this.props.children !== prevProps.children;
        if (elementChanged || (this.props.children && childrenChanged)) {
            this.renderChildren();
        }
    },

    renderChildren: function()
    {
        var fragment = this.state.fragment;
        var rootNode = this.state.rootNode;
        var children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child)
        {
            return React.cloneElement(child, {
                _fragment: fragment,
                _parentNode: rootNode
            });
        });

        var element = React.createElement('div', null, children);
        ReactDOM.render(element, rootNode);
    }

});

module.exports = FragmentTree;
```

And then, there is an component that wrap any components inside the `FragmentTree`. Here is a factory for it.

```
var React = require('react');

function createFragmentTreeElement(Component)
{
    var FragmentTreeElement = React.createClass({

        render: function()
        {
            if (_.isArray(this.props.children)){
                return (
                    <Component {...this.props}>
                        <div>
                            { this.props.children }
                        </div>
                    </Component>
                );
            }

            return (
                <Component {...this.props}>
                    { this.props.children }
                </Component>
            );
        }

    });

    return FragmentTreeElement;
}

module.exports = createFragmentTreeElement;
```

So "fake" components are created like so:

```
var Rectangle = React.createClass({

    render: function()
    {
        return this.props.children || null;
    },

    componentDidMount: function()
    {
        //Draw the rectangle
    },

    componentDidUpdate: function()
    {
        //Update the rectangle
    }

});

module.exports = createFragmentTreeElement(Rectangle);
```

And then this will work:

```
<canvas>
    <FragmentTree>
        <Rectangle>
            <Circle />
            <Circle>
                <Circle />
            </Circle>
        </Rectangle>
    </FragmentTree>
<canvas>
```

It seems to work really well, since any components behave normally. Also the memory and processing should be minimal since it is rendered in a document fragment and the wrapping `<div>` nodes are not really modified.

Is it a good idea? Am I playing with the devil?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How's Virtual DOM implementation is different than createDocumentFragment() if no state is observed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739870/hows-virtual-dom-implementation-is-different-than-createdocumentfragment-if-n)